# What is this plant with red flower and green leaves?

Tags: identification, flowers

What is this plant with red flower and green leaves?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some kind of [Zinnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinnia) definitely.

Comment: Where is the flower growing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rate this as a Zinnia, perhaps a (red variety of) [Zinnia elegans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinnia_elegans). Notice e.g. the [lance-shaped, opposite leaves](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=277260) with [two extra ribs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinnie).

[image: Zinnia elegans 1]